# Dojo: DataGrid from a JsonRest Store

Tags: dojo

I am trying to follow the tutorial here:

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/store_driven_grid/

The tutorial writes:

```
require(["dojo/store/JsonRest"], function(JsonRest){
myStore = new JsonRest({target:"MyData/"});
```

My MyData.json file is placed in ROOT\MyData. If I run the following code

```
...
<script>
var myStore, dataStore, grid;
require(["dojo/store/JsonRest"], function(JsonRest){
    myStore = new JsonRest({target:"MyData/"});
});

require(["dojox/grid/DataGrid",
         "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
         "dojo/domReady!"
], function(DataGrid, ObjectStore){
        grid = new DataGrid({
        store: dataStore = ObjectStore({objectStore: myStore}),
        structure: [
            {name:"State Name", field:"name", width: "200px"},
            {name:"Abbreviation", field:"abbreviation", width: "200px"}
        ]
        }, "target-node-id"); // make sure you have a target HTML element with this id
        grid.startup();
});
</script>
...
```

I get a 404 error on the data if I write "MyData/" and a 416 (Requested Range Not Satisfiable) if I put "MyData/MyData.json".

I know it is something totally stupid, since I can't find anyone have the same problem, but I am unable to see the solution :/

Best regards and thank you for your help!

Andreas

Comment: The url should specify the json file `MyData/MyData.json`.  Can you retrieve the json file with a web browser by accessing the url directly?

Comment: The jsonData's url from that demo is http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/store_driven_grid/demo/MyData/
 but it has a image inside, that not have a fully url too.

Comment: Thank you for your replies!
Craig: If I specify the url like that, I get the 416 error. If I click the link requested in, for example, Chromes debugger, I get the correct JSON.

OammierR: If I remove the Image, it is the same error (416 if I write the entire path, 404 if I follow the tutorial). If I write the full path, it is the same (eg. localhost:8080/Data/...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the data you are providing is not enough to determine whats the problem, but 404 is not found.

So:

1. Make sure you can access the json file via the browser without problems.
2. If you do, use this url in the *{target:"http://URL"}*, this should work.
3. Remember that in the dojo.store.JsonRest target option *{target:"relative or absolute"}*,   if relative path is used, it will look in the path of the executed script.

E.g. If your grid script is in *http://localhost/grid/*, then the JsonRest will look relative to this path. For a target *{target:"MyData.json"}* it will look in *http://localhost/grid/MyData.json*, not finding it, if it where in *http://localhost/MyData.json*

If you still can't solve this post again!!

Comment: Thank you for your reply!. If I do like this `myStore = new JsonRest({target:"http://localhost:8080/Workspace/MyData/Data.json"});` I get a 416, (Requested Range Not Satisfiable). I can view the JSON in my browser using that URL so there is a "connection" between Dojo and the data. The data is valid JSON, so I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I used the code you pasted, and everything works perfect, so proving your problem is related to the data, provably the structure of it.

Data structure for the JsonRest:
[{name: 'Florida', abbreviation: 'FL' }, {name: 'California', abbreviation: 'CL' }]